# How to iterate & search in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I've constructed a dictionary like this:

dir is:

```
{((2, 1), 'South', 1): set([((2, 2), 'South', 1)]), 
((1, 3), 'South', 1): set([((1, 4), 'South', 1)]), 
((5, 3), 'East', 1): set([((4, 3), 'North', 1)]), 
((2, 2), 'South', 1): set([((2, 3), 'East', 1)]),   
((4, 2), 'East', 1): set([((3, 2), 'East', 1)]), 
((1, 1), 'West', 1): set([((2, 1), 'South', 1)])}
```

I want to iterate thru this dictionary like this:

If I have `((2, 1), 'South', 1)` as a key, then I'd like to extract its value `set([((2,2),'South',1)])` and take this as a key and search thru and find its value and so on...

But I'm unable to construct a function for the same. I keep getting just one value and it goes in an infinite loop. I think I may be fetching the values the values incorrectly. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.

Comment: @calccrypto: this is a `dict`. Why not use direct access? `dir_is[((2, 1), 'South', 1)]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget herpaderp. but OP did say iterate

Comment: @calccrypto: fair enough

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
key = ((2, 1), 'South', 1)
while (x.has_key(key)):
    print x[key]
    key = iter(x[key]).next()
```

Comment: `while (dirr.has_key[key]):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Error :(

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you need. Try this:

```
start_pos = ((2, 1), 'South', 1)

d = {...}

visited = set()

def go(pos):
   visited.add(pos)
   for v in d[pos]:
       if v not in visited:
           go(v)

go(start_pos)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def iterate_get_value(my_dict):
    for k,v in my_dict.iteritems():
        if k == ((2, 1), 'South', 1):
            return v
```

Does that work for you?